# Java jar file not working when move to another location

Tags: java, jar

Ok so... here are my steps.

I have a folder on desktop. Lets called it DesktopFolder. Inside desktop folder, i have 2 folders. One called libs and one called src. Inside libs are two jar dependencies. Lets call them jar1 and jar2. Inside src, i have a java file. lets call it MyProgram.java
so I compile them in cmd with

```
javac -cp .;../libs/jar1;../libs/jar2; MyProgram.java
```

that compiles.
now I create a manifest.txt inside my src folder with the following:

```
 Main-Class: MyProgram
    Class-Path: ../libs/jar1 ../libs/jar2
    <a new line>
```

then in my cmd, I navigate to my src directory and do:

```
jar -cvfm MyProgramJar.jar manifest.txt ./../libs MyProgram.class
```

this compiles a jar file called MyProgramJar
this is found inside my src (because i navigated my cmd directory to src)
When I run the executable, it works.
But when i move the MyProgramJar outside to desktop
it says it cannot find library. Why is that? How can I fix it?

The error itself is the JNI error.

Comment: You have to move the whole folder to desktop, not only `Jar` file

Comment: Did you move the lib directory as well?

Comment: @JohnJoe may i know why the whole folder to desktop? the Jar file has the dependencies (when i right click open as... on the jar file, it has a lib folder inside)

Comment: @MadProgrammer why do i need to move the lib directory? the newly created jar has the lib directory does it not? the manifest should be pointing to those dependencies.

Comment: @BinD. Java can't load Jars from within Jars (by default), besides, your `class-path` clearly states that it should look in the `../libs` directory for the additional libraries

Comment: @MadProgrammer ah. I didnt know that. Is there anyway for java to load jars from within jars? I was hoping one single executable will fix the issue. Also, how come eclipse is able to make it load jars from within a jar? I have a friend use my code through eclipse and he was able to make a jar file run anywhere without lib or so.

Comment: @BinD. There are ways, you might extract all the classes from the other libraries and combine them into a single "fat" Jar, this is the most common way, but doesn't take into account what happens if you have files stored at the same location with two or more jars (I use this idea as a "look up" mechanism when creating extensions).

Comment: @MadProgrammer
Does that mean that [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4w_jq6NRWYE) is wrong?

Comment: @BinD. Another way would be to use something like [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/), which would allow you to "embed" the other Jars into a single Jar. It can change the way that you load resources, so beware of that

Comment: @BinD. Did the video work for you? Sorry, I'm not going to sit though it

Comment: @MadProgrammer it did not. Thats why im a bit confuse. Why would people add jars to jars? why will adding jars to jars be a thing?

Comment: @BinD. I'm relating experience up to Java 7 - Maven creates "fat" Jars, but in my experience/needs, that's a shorted sighted method. When will Jars in Jars be a thing? I doubt they will be.  It's much easier to patch a program when it's using multiple Jars (as an example), so you simply replace the Jar you're updating.  A lot of native wrappers will embedded all the Jars internally, which results in a single executed, so I doubt there is a "real" need for it - We tested using OneJar and while it works, we choose to remain with multiple Jars, for patching reasons

Comment: @MadProgrammer ah. thank you so very much! I understand it now. it all makes sense now :D how do I give u an upvote or anything?

Comment: @BinD. If you want, answer the question yourself with what you've learnt and the solution(s) you've tried, then you might help some one else 

Answer (score 1):

hmmmm. thanks to @MadProgrammer (from the comment section). I learned that a jar file cannot access another jar file from within. The classpath you put into manifest is all relative classpath. Once you move the jar file outside, it wont be able to locate the file that your program depends on. There are ways around it like "fat" jars as mentioned by Madprogrammer that allows a jar to access another jar from within.

Another way is opening up dependencies jar and simply moving the files out of its own jar. That way, your code can reference those libraries directly.

A personal friend of mine used eclipse to build the jar. That seem to work even if you have a jar within a jar and you move the jar around. I'm assuming eclipse did something just like "fat" jar.